# What is a C# solution and how to use it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution

I am new to C# (coming from Python and C) and when I start a new project in Monodevelop or Visual Studio, the project is put in a "solution" container.

I had a look at Microsoft description of what a solution is but I don't really understand the benefit of this and how I should use it.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b142f8e7.aspx) says:

> A project is contained, in a logical sense and in the file system, within a solution, which may contain one or more projects, along with build information, Visual Studio window settings, and any miscellaneous files that aren't associated with any project. In a literal sense, the solution is a text file with its own unique format; it is generally not intended to be edited by hand.

Could someone explain what "solutions" are here for?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx

Comment: Short, a [solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx) contains multiple projects.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx

Comment: A solution is a "group of projects". Ideally, they should be related. For example, if you use the 3 layer architecture, a solution would contain 3 projects, BL,DAL and PRS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A solution is a workspace that combines multiple projects, which are usually related to each other. The construct is very useful in situations when some code needs to be shared among multiple projects.

For example, if you are developing a web site with a separate server-side component, you could segregate it into several related projects:

- A project containing common interfaces, producing a DLL
- A project containing database definition, producing an RDBMS deployment script
- A project containing server-side API implementation, producing an executable
- A web site project, producing an IIS deployment script

These four projects are connected to each other. Placing them into a single solution lets you access individual parts, while taking advantage of common indexing that Visual Studio does for you to simplify searches for usage and to help with refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

While all the other answers are correct, I feel they are missing the conceptual reason.

A project is a Self contained piece of work, this could be a a Win Forms Application, a Class Library, a Web Site, Web Service, etc.

However, the Solution to a problem may require multiple parts to work i.e. the Win Forms application needs the Class Library to work and so does the Web Service, but the Website might need the Web Service.

The Solution File is the Conceptualised model of this.

If your problem is the Win Forms App, then you create a solution and add the Win Forms App and the Library.

If your problem is the Web Site then you create a solution and add the Web Site, the Web Service, and the Library.

The project that contains the library can be the same in both solutions meaning you don't have to duplicate code or keep track of dependencies for your projects because everything it depends on, is in your solution already.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is a "Container" for your projects.

For example: If you write a windows application you could have one project for the UI-stuff and one project for the Backend-logic.

To easily work on both projects, you have them bundled into one solution not only allowing you to debug through both projects but also to build them in an order you specify.

Answer (score 2):

> **Advantages**
>
> Solutions allow you to concentrate on developing and deploying your
>   projects, instead of sorting through all the details of managing
>   project files, components, and objects. Each Visual Studio solution
>   allows you to:
>
> Work on multiple projects within the same instance of the IDE.
>
> Work on items using settings and options that apply to an entire set
>   of projects.
>
> Use Solution Explorer to help develop and deploy your application.
>
> Manage additional files opened outside the context of a solution or
>   project.

Read the whole article for more details: [**Solutions as Containers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df8st53z(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Solution contains one or more projects. For example, a solution contains a web project, a mobile project and a windows service project. So, solution of my application has 3 project.

Answer (score 1):

A solution groups all of your projects (dll's), files, configs etc together, the quote you provided is quite self-explanatory:

> A project is contained, in a logical sense and in the file system, within a solution...

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of a solution is that you can add multiple projects in it.
This is good if you have a project which uses your own libraries

Then you solution will contain your main project, and your library projects. And they can all depend on eachother so that they build in the right order.

Without a solution you would only have your main project and you would have to build your libraries seperatly

Answer (score -2):

In a nutshell: A solution is the sum total of your work.

Comment: This is too vague. If you think something is missing in the existing answers, please elaborate.